# Convert respondsToSelector and performSelector from Objective C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

As the title states, I'm having difficulty converting the following code from objective c to swift.

```
UIView * (^viewForContent)(BookObject *) = ^UIView*(BookObject * content) {
    NSString * title = content.title;
    NSString * markdown = nil;
    if ([content respondsToSelector:@selector(markdown)]) {
        markdown = [content performSelector:@selector(markdown)];
    }
    return viewForItem(title, markdown);
};
```

Below is my attempt.

```
var viewForContent = { (content: BookObject) -> UIView in
    var title = content.title
    var markdown: String? = nil
    if content.responds(to: Selector(markdown!)) {
        markdown = content.perform(Selector(markdown!)) //error: Cannot assign value of type 'Unmanaged<AnyObject>?' to type 'String?'
    }
    return viewForItem(title!, markdown!);
}
```

BookObject inherits from NSObject. The issue with this code is I get an error on the `perform(aSelector: Selector!)` function. I'm very new to swift and I have been having a hard time narrowing down the issue with my code. What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

As requested here is more information about the BookObject and what this block of code is doing. There is another object called BookTextObject which inherits from BookObject. This BookTextObject has a property called markdown, but the BookObject does not. The `respondsToSelector` and `performSelector` is there to check if markdown is a property on content, and if so to also set the value in that markdown property to this markdown variable.

I didn't write this code, I'm just trying to convert it to swift. Furthermore, It doesn't ever seem like the result of the if statement will ever be false (i.e. it seems that content is always a BookTextObject), but since I didn't write this code, I'd rather not take out the if statement for fear of breaking something.

Comment: What you're asking to do is possible but it's unSwifty. You should rethink it. You know this is a BookObject so why wouldn't it respond to `markdown`? If there's a reason, explain it by showing us more about what a BookObject is. Then we can tell you what to do. You're doing some sort of string-to-method conversion here, but Swift does like to do that and doesn't need to.

Comment: Also your code makes no sense so far because `markdown` is `nil`. Even in Objective-C it never takes on another value before you call `respondsToSelector`. So what did this code even do in Objective-C?

Comment: Can you share your exact error and exact scenario

Comment: The usual *swifty* way is a protocol.

Comment: The usual swift way is not to use a force-downcast variable.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: @matt, In my question I mentioned that I'm new to swift, I literally just started learning it two days ago. So if it's unSwifty, I don't know what you mean. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is another object called BookTextObject which inherits from BookObject. This BookTextObject has a property called `markdown`, but the BookObject does not

So the way to write that in Swift is to cast `content` (a BookObject) down to a BookTextObject (a BookObject subclass) safely and conditionally:

```
if let bookTextObject = content as? BookTextObject {
    markdown = bookTextObject.markdown
}
```

If that's the only thing you need to do with the cast reference, you can write it in an even more condensed way:

```
markdown = (content as? BookTextObject)?.markdown
```

After that line, the local `markdown` will be `nil` if we couldn't cast down.